# How to import txt with strings of different length into matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to import a txt file , there are many columns in the text.

```
delimiterIn = ',';
C=importdata('userdata.txt',delimiterIn);
```

This works if there are no strings in user data.txt, but in fact i have the strings as username. For example, the real row like this: 142,'A266KTWY0HBD2F',    143,'A1RROEUFR0F2DU',   144,'AX4ZTKCHL6OXA', the username string length is not exactly the same, how could I import also the strings to matlab? thanks.

Comment: Are the apostrophes (single quotes) actually in your file or are you adding them to denote a string?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Can give an example of a short input file, and what do you expect the result to be after the import?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textscan` to deal with arbitrarily deliminated strings. The strings are stored in cell arrays so they can be of different lengths.

The [MathWorks reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) is fairly complete.

Answer (score 0):

As Mozglubov mentioned use textscan. In your case you have only integers and strings therefore use the following:

```
fileID = fopen('userdata.txt', 'r');
C = textscan(fileID,'%d %s %d %s %d %s', 'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);
```

If you have doubles instead of integers, use %f instead %d. And please check Matworks [textscan](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) reference for detailed properties of the function.